# Decoding JSON for single object vs array of objects in swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift, decodable

I'm fairly new to the swift programming language and have been trying to get this to work for the last week or so. I'm working with an existing API that returns JSON data whose structure changes a little depending on how many venues get returned.

The real structure is somewhat more complicated, but this example illustrates the problem. In one flavor of result, I get a single venue returned like:

```
{
  "totalItems": 21,
  "pageSize": 2,
  "venues": {
    "venue":
    {
       "name": "Venue Name 1"
       "location": "Location A",
       "showCount": "4"
    }
  }
}
```

In another flavor of result, I get an array of venues returned:

```
{
  "totalItems": 21,
  "pageSize": 2,
  "venues": {
    "venue":
    [{
       "name": "Venue Name 1"
       "location": "Location A",
       "showCount": "4"
    },
    {
       "name": "Venue Name 2"
       "location": "Location B",
       "showCount": "2"
    }]
  }
}
```

Yes - the owner of this API should have returned an array regardless, but they didn't and it cannot be changed.

I was able to get this to decode properly for an array of venues (or even if no venues were passed), but it aborts when a single venue is passed (due to the structure variation of course). My code also worked when I changed it to accommodate a single venue, but then returns of multiple venues aborted.

What I'd like to do is decode either variation into an internal structure containing an array regardless of which variation I receive, thus making things far simpler for me to deal with programmatically afterward. Something like this:

```
struct Response: Decodable {
    let totalItems: Int
    let pageSize: Int
    let venues: VenueWrapper

    struct VenueWrapper: Decodable {
        let venue: [Venue]     // This might contain 0, 1, or more than one venues
    }

    struct Venue: Decodable {
        let name: String
        let location: String
        let showCount: Int
    }
}
```

Note: In the actual JSON response, there are actually several substructures like this in the response (e.g., a single structure vs an array of structures) which is why I felt simply creating an alternate structure was not a good solution.

I'm hoping someone has come across this before.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide a closer-to-reality example of what you have to work with? You're missing commas, so that's not valid JSON. And your `Response` can't be decoded as-is because the `showCount`s are strings.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The actual JSON is quite a bit more complicated so I tried to prune it a bit to concentrate on the real problem which is the array or not array part. In my own code, I have added the custom logic for converting the strings to integers, but didn't include it.

Comment: Sorry - a "return"  triggered posting my comment before I was ready. (I'm still new to posting here.) I was trying to avoid posting the entire json since it's quite lengthy. I probably should have removed the quotes around the showCount item since it detracts from the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create your own decoder,

```
struct Response: Decodable {
    let totalItems: Int
    let pageSize: Int
    let venues: VenueWrapper

    struct VenueWrapper: Decodable {
        var venue: [Venue]

        init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
            venue = []
            if let singleVenue = try? values.decode(Venue.self, forKey: CodingKeys.venue) {
                //if a single venue decoded append it to array
                venue.append(singleVenue)
            } else if let multiVenue = try? values.decode([Venue].self, forKey: CodingKeys.venue) {
                //if a multi venue decoded, set it as venue
                venue = multiVenue
            }

            enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case venue }
        }
    }

    struct Venue: Decodable {
        let name: String
        let location: String
        let showCount: String
    }
}
```

Comment: That works!!!  I was on the right trail, but you have elegantly solved the problem.  Thank you so very much!!

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for `VenueWrapper`.

```swift
struct Response {
  let totalItems: Int
  let pageSize: Int
  let venues: [Venue]

  struct Venue {
    let name: String
    let location: String
    let showCount: Int
  }
}
```

You'll need to write your own initializer. Unfortunately, I don't think there's a way to eliminate the boilerplate for the not-goofily-encoded properties.

Even if you never need to encode it, making `Response` `Codable`, not just `Decodable`, will give you access to an auto-generated `CodingKeys`.

```swift
extension Response: Codable {
  init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    totalItems = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .totalItems)
    pageSize = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .pageSize)
    venues = try container.decode(key: .venues)
  }
}
```

That last line relies on a protocol and extension which you can use for any other types that are similarly "encoded".

```swift
protocol GoofilyEncoded: Codable {
  /// Must have exactly one case.
  associatedtype GoofyCodingKey: CodingKey
}

extension KeyedDecodingContainer {
  func decode<Decodable: GoofilyEncoded>(key: Key) throws -> [Decodable] {
    let nestedContainer = try self.nestedContainer(
      keyedBy: Decodable.GoofyCodingKey.self,
      forKey: key
    )

    let key = nestedContainer.allKeys.first!

    do {
      return try nestedContainer.decode([Decodable].self, forKey: key)
    }
    catch {
      return try [nestedContainer.decode(Decodable.self, forKey: key)]
    }
  }
}
```

All your types that might be encoded in arrays, *or not* ‍♂️, will need a one-case enum, like so:

```swift
extension Response.Venue: GoofilyEncoded {
  enum GoofyCodingKey: CodingKey {
    case venue
  }
}
```

Comment: You're right - I really didn't want VenueWrapper but it mirrored the JSON structure I was being passed. I like your approach because it gets rid of that unneeded structure and more importantly it helps me better create a generic way to cover a similar situation I have with other elements in the same API response. I'm going to have to study this a bit more to see how to use this approach since I'm yet proficient in this style (yet). I've got other parts of my code that could also make use of the same sort of generic design skills so it will be worth effort. Thanks for the assist!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need so much code, all you need to do is a manual decoding like this one:

```
struct Response: Decodable {
let totalItems: Int
let pageSize: Int
let venues: [Venue]

// Manual decoder
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    totalItems = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .totalItems)
    pageSize = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .pageSize)
    
    var array: [Venue] = []
    
    if let single = try? container.decode(Venue.self, forKey: .venues) {
        array = [single]
    } else if let multi = try? container.decode([Venue].self, forKey: .venues) {
        array = multi
    }
    
    venues = array
}

struct Venue: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let location: String
    let showCount: Int
}
```

}